# Why do some transistor packages have multiple leads for the emitter?

Tags: bjt, packages, terminal

I want to use a BJT transistor (edit: BFU768F, https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/BFU768F.pdf) that looks like this:

[image]

I think I get why lead 1 is bigger than the rest. It's because both collector and base current have to go through there, right? But what is the use for lead 3?

Comment: There's more than one reason that might be done.  It would help if you would _edit your question_ with a link to the datasheet for the exact transistor you wish to use, then it will be more apparent why it was done _for that transistor_.

Comment: A BJT is controlled by the base-emitter. Having a separate lead separate from the collector currents can help in some cases.

Comment: Lead 1 is probably wider than the others primarily to mark it as "Pin 1"

Answer (score 4):

According to [patent US 5,107,326](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/c4/32/b8/e664a889fd986f/US5107326.pdf) :

> Bipolar, high-frequency broadband transistors having the SOT-143
> format with four electrical terminals 1-4 achieve noticeably greater
> amplification at high frequencies when compared to SMD components
> having the SOT-23 format that only has three electrical terminals,
> this because of reduced emitter-lead inductance and because of reduced
> capacitive coupling between the collector and the base.

The latter consideration also points to having the emitters on diagonally opposite corners so the base and collector are also diagonally opposite, also mentioned several times in the patent.

This particular 1992 patent covers the lead frame construction as shown below:

[image]

The NXP document refers to the package as "reverse pinned". [Here](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-BFP840FESD-DS-v02_00-EN.pdf) is an Infineon SiGe part with the mirror image pinout shown in the test configuration:

[image]

In the CE configuration, the grounded emitters help reduce the C-B coupling which would directly affect the gain.

As to the SOT343 package design, it is a small package (important for RF) and used in [other applications such as diodes](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-BAS125SERIES-DS-v01_01-en.pdf), so was probably chosen for a combination of reasons.

SiGe transistor construction is collector-down (as in the die back is connected to the collector) like ordinary silicon transistors, however conducting heat out appears to be a secondary consideration in this case for whatever reason(s)-  (note that the patent illustration shows the collector connected to the fattest lead to better conduct heat out, as with ordinary Si transistors).

Answer (score 1):

If the leads were the same size, think: how would you inspect correct placement on the PCB? :)  (Sure, there might be a label, or polarity mark on the package.  But sometimes those are omitted, or invisible.)

Indeed, there are dual transistors (SOT-23-6, SOT-363) without polarity marks, since it doesn't matter which way they're placed; the pinout is rotationally symmetric.

As for repeat pins, it may simply be a default.  Most BJTs are built with the bulk of the die chip as collector, with the base and emitter stuff (or drain, gate and source respectively, for MOSFETs) built on top.  So the die is bonded to the lead frame -- which might come out on multiple pins for better thermal performance, perhaps -- and those happen to be the collector.  The remaining pins are wire-bonded, giving little thermal conduction.

Other types may prioritize electrical impedance.  RF amplifiers in particular, prefer common-emitter connection for maximum efficiency and power output, and a low impedance connection between emitter and circuit ground plane is needed.

Given the massive 110 GHz fT, the latter is surely the case for your example part.

Answer (score 0):

Consider thermal considerations, they have to get the most heat out the most efficient way. The fastest way is usually connect the back metal of the die to the pin with the largest surface area. For example N-Channel mosfets usually have the center lead as drain which is normally the back metal and connected to the TAB. Similar with transistors however the back metal in NPN transistors is the collector. There are many ICs that have several pins connected together and this is also done on the lead frame to increase the heat transfer. The least effective place to place a heat sink is on the plastic tab. There are going to be exceptions and this has evolved over 50 plus years.

Answer (score -3):

They could be BJTs for [TTL gates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor%E2%80%93transistor_logic)

Comment: It doesn't have two emitters, though, just one emitter with two pins.